# Select With Union In SQL

Tags: sql

Why when i run the syntax in sql and the result will be double data?

The command is :

```
SELECT     1 AS Urut, M.Kode_Project, M.Nama_Project, M.Kode_Panel, D .Nama_Stater1, D .Tipe, D .Komponen, D .Pole, D .Amps, D .Merek, D .Qty, D .IsTitipan
FROM         TransM M INNER JOIN
                      TransD D ON M.Kode_Project = D .Kode_Project AND M.Kode_Panel = D .Kode_Panel
WHERE     M.Kode_Project = '17-0002' AND M.Kode_Panel = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT     2 AS Urut, M.Kode_Project, M.Nama_Project, M.Kode_Panel, M.Nama_Stater1, 'COOPER (' + SubString(Kode, 5, 100) + ')' AS Tipe, 
                      ' (' + LT + ') X ' + CONVERT(VarChar(20), Lapis) AS Komponen, '' AS Pole, '' AS Amps, ' IMPORT ' AS Merek, 1 AS Qty, 0 AS IsTitipan
FROM         TransM M INNER JOIN
                      TransW W ON M.Kode_Project = W.Kode_Project AND M.Kode_Panel = W.Kode_Panel
WHERE     LEFT(Kode, 1) <= 'B' AND M.Kode_Project = '17-0002' AND M.Kode_Panel = 'A'
```

What's the wrong in the command?, Thank's for who's helping.

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (Some product specific constructions there...)

Comment: Do you just want to use UNION instead of UNION ALL to eliminate duplicates?? Is that what you asking?

Comment: What's wrong with the result you get? Simplify, and sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: The result from my select is double.

Answer (score 1):

UNION ALL will merge duplicate rows from result of two select, change

> UNION ALL

to just

> UNION

this will remove duplicate rows from the result

Comment: Note that the first select includes the literal 1, and the second the literal 2. I.e. no common rows!

Comment: After i change to union the result from the second select result still double data too.

Comment: could you share some data set of the table?

Comment: Now i know the problem of my select. Thanks all especially Mr.Raj

Comment: nice to know, you had solved the problem, if possible give some details in the update how the problem is solved, might help readers of the question